# Ag-grid event to identify changed rows/Values

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to find out a solution to implement save functionality after the values in the ag-grid is changed.

I have an angular2 ag-grid with almost 100 columns but only 4 columns are editable. And on click of a save button on my web page i want to post only the changed values if any by the user, to the database. Is there any event which i can use to identify changed rows in the grid? Or any other suggestion to implement such scenario?

I looked at rowValueChanged and cellValueChanged event, but these event will trigger after every change? I need to get the values only after the user hits save button.

Comment: is this Angular or AngularJs?  Your question body says [tag:Angular] (2) but you tagged [tag:AngularJs] (1).  They are not the same framework.

Comment: I have this same requirement. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: nope, i used the cellchanged event. I have raised a feature request in github, which was closed. https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2105

Comment: @JohnDewell - You could vote for the issue on github and then it might be in priority for ag-grid team